# Correct JSON path for sample json

Tags: json

I am trying to get the correct JSON path in order to correctly map columns in azure data factory. Currently I have this as the given path.

```
$..CUSTOMFIELDS[?(@.FIELD_NAME == ‘PROJECT_FIELD_1’)].FIELD_VALUE
```

With this as the sample data...

```json
[
    {
        "PROJECT_ID": 1463616,
        "PROJECT_NAME": "P0303 - 1010 Common Garage",
        "STATUS": "IN PROGRESS",
        "PROJECT_DETAILS": "539 spaces, Post Pay, Garage, Unattended, Full Automation, Covered",
        "STARTED_DATE": "2014-07-17 00:00:00",
        "COMPLETED_DATE": null,
        "OPPORTUNITY_ID": null,
        "CATEGORY_ID": 1912811,
        "PIPELINE_ID": null,
        "STAGE_ID": null,
        "IMAGE_URL": null,
        "VISIBLE_TO": "OWNER",
        "OWNER_USER_ID": 583590,
        "DATE_CREATED_UTC": "2014-07-10 16:20:59",
        "DATE_UPDATED_UTC": "2020-12-17 17:49:19",
        "LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE_UTC": "2021-06-28 15:37:49",
        "NEXT_ACTIVITY_DATE_UTC": null,
        "CREATED_USER_ID": 583590,
        "RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID": 583590,
        "VISIBLE_TEAM_ID": null,
        "CUSTOMFIELDS": [
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "GET_Valet__c",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "YES",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "GET_Valet__c"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_1",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "New Orleans, LA",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_1"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_10",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "1010 Common St New Orleans, LA, 70112",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_10"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_11",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "99 Commercial Operations",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_11"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_12",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "P303",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_12"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_13",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "1010 Common",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_13"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_15",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "Cash + CC",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_15"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_16",
                "FIELD_VALUE": 0,
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_16"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_17",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "0",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_17"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_19",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "6' 5\"",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_19"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_2",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "https://www.premiumparking.com/P303",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_2"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_20",
                "FIELD_VALUE": 29.953705,
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_20"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_21",
                "FIELD_VALUE": -90.073686,
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_21"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_22",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "2020-07-09 00:00:00",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_22"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_23",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "2020-02-28 00:00:00",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_23"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_24",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "Yes",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_24"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_25",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "Ricky Dunn",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_25"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_26",
                "FIELD_VALUE": 13,
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_26"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_27",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "T2 Luke II Pay Machine",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_27"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_28",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "NA",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_28"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_3",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "1010 Common St New Orleans, LA, 70112",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_3"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_30",
                "FIELD_VALUE": 0,
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_30"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_5",
                "FIELD_VALUE": 539,
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_5"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_6",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "0",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_6"
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "PROJECT_FIELD_9",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "2010-02-01 00:00:00",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "PROJECT_FIELD_9"
            }
        ],
        "TAGS": [],
        "LINKS": [
            {
                "DETAILS": "",
                "ROLE": "Owner Contact / VIP",
                "LINK_ID": 44340470,
                "OBJECT_NAME": "Project",
                "OBJECT_ID": 1463616,
                "LINK_OBJECT_NAME": "Contact",
                "LINK_OBJECT_ID": 67999750
            },
            {
                "DETAILS": "",
                "ROLE": "COI",
                "LINK_ID": 110651393,
                "OBJECT_NAME": "Project",
                "OBJECT_ID": 1463616,
                "LINK_OBJECT_NAME": "Organisation",
                "LINK_OBJECT_ID": 82096727
            },
            {
                "DETAILS": "",
                "ROLE": "COI",
                "LINK_ID": 110651854,
                "OBJECT_NAME": "Project",
                "OBJECT_ID": 1463616,
                "LINK_OBJECT_NAME": "Contact",
                "LINK_OBJECT_ID": 174225479
            },
            {
                "DETAILS": null,
                "ROLE": "COI",
                "LINK_ID": 161207971,
                "OBJECT_NAME": "Project",
                "OBJECT_ID": 1463616,
                "LINK_OBJECT_NAME": "Organisation",
                "LINK_OBJECT_ID": 114268945
            },
            {
                "DETAILS": null,
                "ROLE": "COI",
                "LINK_ID": 161327410,
                "OBJECT_NAME": "Project",
                "OBJECT_ID": 1463616,
                "LINK_OBJECT_NAME": "Organisation",
                "LINK_OBJECT_ID": 114310505
            },
            {
                "DETAILS": null,
                "ROLE": "COI",
                "LINK_ID": 163837136,
                "OBJECT_NAME": "Project",
                "OBJECT_ID": 1463616,
                "LINK_OBJECT_NAME": "Organisation",
                "LINK_OBJECT_ID": 82096763
            },
            {
                "DETAILS": null,
                "ROLE": "VIP",
                "LINK_ID": 166579158,
                "OBJECT_NAME": "Project",
                "OBJECT_ID": 1463616,
                "LINK_OBJECT_NAME": "Contact",
                "LINK_OBJECT_ID": 241879003
            },
            {
                "DETAILS": null,
                "ROLE": "VIP",
                "LINK_ID": 166579346,
                "OBJECT_NAME": "Project",
                "OBJECT_ID": 1463616,
                "LINK_OBJECT_NAME": "Contact",
                "LINK_OBJECT_ID": 79436911
            },
            {
                "DETAILS": null,
                "ROLE": "VIP",
                "LINK_ID": 166579448,
                "OBJECT_NAME": "Project",
                "OBJECT_ID": 1463616,
                "LINK_OBJECT_NAME": "Contact",
                "LINK_OBJECT_ID": 241879220
            },
            {
                "DETAILS": null,
                "ROLE": "VIP",
                "LINK_ID": 166579660,
                "OBJECT_NAME": "Project",
                "OBJECT_ID": 1463616,
                "LINK_OBJECT_NAME": "Contact",
                "LINK_OBJECT_ID": 88548336
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read in [this documentation](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/):

> Please note, that the return value of jsonPath is an array, which is
> also a valid JSON structure.

So basically it always returns an array. You have to fix your path

```
var vieldValue = jsonPath(json,"$..CUSTOMFIELDS[?(@.FIELD_NAME == 
'PROJECT_FIELD_1')]")[0].FIELD_VALUE;
```

result

```
New Orleans, LA
```